# What eugenic plan could a human nation use to turn beastfolk into petfolk without using force?

Tags: society, politics, eugenics

So in my world the human empire have lived together with humanoid beastfolk: think werewolf/lycanth, minotaur, big feline like tiger/lionfolk or humanoid jungle cat, etc.

They are relatively smart or sentient, almost like human-level inteligent/sentient; the thing is they consider humans as their equal or part of their pack, whereas humans think of them as nothing more than just as pets or slave workforce. I am struggling to find a way for these humans to trick their fellow beastfolk into selective breeding so as to dumb them down or make them more loyal to human: think of werewolf/lycanth into dogfolk, minotaur into dairy minotaur, orc into pigfolk, the feline into catfolk.

The dogfolk is to turn into the army or guards, or a plaything pet for humans; the feline to guard the farmland from pests, hunters or forest rangers; the minotaur to produce meat and milk; and also the pigfolk for food and pig related products. Yes, my humans will eat both of them.

They have to manage to selectively breed them into those docile versions, without the rest, the pure beastfolk, finding out that they are being tricked by the humans.

Before this happened, the beastfolk could do whatever job they want; although they still have savage tendencies or lack of self control: especially since they have sharp teeth, claws, and horns/tusks, which is also one of the reason human want to tone them down.

**The political scene is dominated by humans**, so the beastfolk is currently just citizen; they don't care much regarding human politics outside of taxation.

**Concentration camps or similar like is out of the question, as is any use of force**, I want a more civil way without making dissent or provoking suspicion/fear in the remaining beastfolk, because despite how mighty the human race is with their advanced technology, you still don't want wild beasts wreak havoc or run amok in your country.

**Religions or religion-related mechanisms are out of the question**, because the beastfolk religion is almost nonexistent or at best shamanistic: ancestor spirit or food chain type of religions (you know the life and death recycle thing). Human religions are pretty speciesist: like, only human will gain salvation or go to heaven. They dont condemn the nonbeliever though, because it is exclusive to humans, so beastfolk cannot join nor care about it. Also, the humans are not fanatic to their religion so they don't hate beastfolk, they just think of them as lesser beings than them and enjoy the beastfolk companion as their pets. The religions are also not influential in the politics outside of influencing the human mindset. They don't want to use force against beastfolk.

**Law protecting beastfolk from cruelty exist**, although turning them into consumable meat or other products is actually fine: it fits beastfolk religions/mindset as I mentioned with the food chain thing; they generally don't like to waste the dead (though they are fine to burn, bury or decompose it, if the corpse is beyond consumable or contain deadly disease), and they do share the medically checked meat of their dead fellows to be consumed. Still, killing or murdering the beastfolk is not fine (at least before they turn into meat petfolk). The problem is them realizing they are betrayed and bred to be killed as industrial meat or getting dumber or breed to be slave.

**Machines, chemicals or drugs (including magic) as a brainwashing method to instantly turn them into petfolk without using selective breeding method is also out of the question.**

**I have thought about a dating agency**, but I am not sure about the effectiveness, and it's not like all of them go to the dating agency to find their mate (since I don't want to enforce it). They are also quite proud and are disinclined to use something like that.

**I have also thought about a way to make a trending/viral hype to attract this beastfolk to unconsciously follow the selective breeding** (think of teenage viral/trending challenge like condom snorting, ice bucket challenge, etc.) to create something like: elephants start to breed with tuskless male, because tuskless elephant is the hot thing right now. The thing is I don't know what kind of trending would do it, and I am not sure about the effectiveness either. Besides, they don't have internet or television yet, although they do have paper or newspaper including book as the medium (privately owned) - but as I mentioned religion is out of the question.

**The human civilization is the industrial civilization**, or something like that I guess.... but the leader is not dictator or a tyrant (in a way like using an iron fist or enforcing their rule or law).

**It's fine if the selective breeding happened before the empire founded**, like during caveman times for example.

**Also beastfolk cannot breed with humans**, only with their own species or closely related species.

Feel free to correct my grammar and edit the tags, since I am not sure which tag is appropriate for my question.

Comment: Chemicals/drugs/magical aren't hollowed to brainwash, but is it hollowed for genetic change?

Comment: @Rorp only allowed natural selective breeding, but  i dont know is it involve drug or machine though if it is then its fine, but if you mean something like drug them to turn them into gay like some internet conspiracy then its not allowed.

Comment: What on _earth_ does being gay have to do with being domesticated?

Comment: @StarfishPrime i mean it as an example of this kind of method, basically instantenously turning them into domesticate version without using selective breeding. you know stuff like the internet conspiracy about [gay bomb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gay_bomb) thing

Comment: @LiJun I was more likely to think about a chemical/virus put in the air that target "non humans" and make that now they give birth to babies that are "petfolk" (somehow accelerate the process by a factor 50000)

Comment: @Rorp seems basically no different like the instant domestic gene or gay bomb thing so i guess no, i want it to be selective breeding method like how most domesticate animal experience it, but correct me if iam wrong though if selective breeding actually use such method.

Comment: Artificial selection schemes usually involve control over breeding, and selection/rejection for characteristics. It's not clear if the question is about assuaging the human society's guilt, or merely dressing up the control and selection to be culturally acceptable to the human society.

Comment: @user535733 i dont quite get what you mean, but my question is not about human society guilt or make it culturally acceptable, as you can see in my description the human is fine with it, i just want to know a workable scheme for this beastfolk getting artificial selection or selective breeding method without them realizing it.

Comment: Would the process that turned wolves (and wolf-like critters) into dogs pass? Would it count as force? Basically, the aggressive individuals that didn't come when they were called were not allowed mates. Or became lunch.

Comment: @puppetsock seems forceful to me, beside they have free will and free choice to mate with whoever they love, the human empire cant block them against that. but hiring conditions like Kaizerham answer is ok i guess.

Comment: Eugenics as a concept is inherently based on the application of force

Comment: @NixonCranium so what the name for the non enforcement one ? english is not my first language, and feel free to edit it to the correct term for what i describe, if eugenic is not suitable term for it.

Comment: @NixonCranium I disagree. There's nothing oxymoronic about "subtle eugenics".

Comment: @Li Jun selective breeding is the neutral term. In the western world eugenics has a strong association with Nazism and white supremacism.

Answer (score 6):

**You cannot be explicit about your eugenics, but you can always set hiring conditions...**

You want to make werewolves into a private army. Hire them! Put out ads for Innocuous Security Company Incorporated; or maybe even the regular army. Then set a hefty wage, and watch the applications roll in. Now, only hire the most cooperative of them. The ones with the traits you want. Yet, allow (encourage) them to take their families with them and go live in a little [planned community](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planned_community), owned by the company. A village for the soldiers and soldiers-in-training. They can leave any time they want, but in the village they live a life of luxury, so they won't do that often.

Repeat for the felines and the other beasts. Set up companies which hire the beasts that already have at least some of the qualities you want, and make every employee and their families live in secluded villages. Turning orcs into pigs may be more difficult; just have them and the minotaurs do social tasks that are not dull enough to bore them, but still encourage cooperativeness with each other and especially the humans. Meanwhile, make sure they are very well fed.

So the first generation of new employees will already be useful to the human empire. The first generation can be educated. The second, third generation; they will be born in those villages, and will of course be educated in the school that the company provides. Have said education focus on the same traits, and the next few generations will be steadily indoctrinated.

Practise eugenics by giving promotion to the most suitable employees. It is perfectly justified: the wolf company rewards those who follow orders, the cat company rewards those who hunt the best, and the minotaur and orc army rewards those who do not stubborn. Also give promotions to less intelligent members of each species, and the fattest orcs and minotaurs. Encourage those with promotions to have even more babies.

And as a final piece of the puzzle: provoke wars between the beasts who live outside the communities. Do not attack them: make them fight each other through intrigue and leaking secrets; without being noticed of course. Meanwhile tell the war-torn villages about your communities of healthy workers, and tell those communities about how terrible it is outside. More people will come in, and you can be stricter about your hiring conditions while the outside population still slowly dwindles.

If your companies last long enough, over the course of as few as a couple dozen generations ([as the Russians did with foxes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domesticated_red_fox)) you could drastically alter these species into dumb and obedient pets.

Comment: Also (and more evil): Maybe take all those uncooperative wolves into your army as well. But in their own  "special strike packs" which just so happen to always be the front line or  head that suicide charge.  That way you also thin out the unwanted ones

Answer (score 4):

**Breed a tiger into a cow.**

> But as Rick Barrows at USDA pointed out, this is a question of
>   perspective.   "We can farm the tigers of the sea," he told me, "as
>   long as we feed them hay."... And so we've reached a crossroads with
>   salmon.  Either we can invest money and effort into making a more and
>   more artificial salmon, one whose very genetic components are
>   profoundly different from their ancestors, or we can simply say that
>   we've gone far enough with selective breeding.

From [Four Fish: The Future of the Last Wild Food.](https://www.amazon.com/s?k=9781101442296&i=stripbooks&linkCode=qs)

The salmon is an example of what you want.  The ancestors of farm salmon are fierce oceangoing predators.  Farm salmon are cowlike meat makers, content to live in close quarters in ponds and eat kibble.

1. Food is key.  Your humans need to have plentiful food.  Those demihumans they choose to be breeders will be bigger and healthier because of this plentiful food.
2. Assuming mammal type breeding where one male is sire of many offspring, humans choose the male.  They choose him for docility and tractability.  At sites where demihumans eat human food, the demihumans there are products of the chosen male.  Other males born into this group are dealt with according to culturally acceptable norms.  They could be culled, or castrated, or maybe they are sent out to join the wild ones.  Breeders wil also pay attention to females; those with undesirable characteristics will not be allowed to breed and those with desirable characteristcs will have several offspring over their lives.  The desirable genetics of a given sire could be amplified by inbreeding with his daughters and granddaughters.  This is just animal husbandry.
3. DNA aside, because of human protection and plentiful food, the domestic demihumans have greater genetic fitness.  There are more of them that survive to reproductive age and those that do have more offspring.
4. Over time the domesticated demihumans will become more tractable and docile if that is what they are bred for.  Or more intelligent, or larger, or woolier.  Again - just animal husbandry.
5. As with the salmon, those domesticated demihumans that leave human company and join the wild ones will bring their genes with them.  Wild salmon today have some genes introduced by domestic salmon escapees.  The wild salmon are less wild.  This will gradually push the wild demihuman population towards docility and tractability as well.

Comment: but they have free will, and thats one of the problem, since i cant block them to mate with the one they love nor kick or castrate the undesirable one, since i consider that as blatant enforcing, the indirect way is fine like the food chain reaction to make them attractive or desirable, also i kinda doubt they will deliberately do inbreeding since for now i dont consider inbreeding is part of their culture norm either. i mean as a current beastfolk they have free will compare to the petfolk version.

Answer (score 1):

I think it will be very hard to do so. I'll take all "possible way" I figured out, and say what is the main problem.

### Politic

Look like the easiest way. You make a law that say that peoples with some "wild characteristics" have to be sterilise... Well you can't do it without force

### Let time make it

As you said, the desision of turning all beastfolks into petfolks can start from prehistoric time. But since beastfolks have human-like intelligence, you can't make it without force from human (by enslaving them), because "wild characteristics" will make them survive. And science pointed out that, without mass manipulation (see later), most peoples target characteristics that tell "I'll survive and give those super characteristics to my childs" so, as for animals, only slavery will make it work.

### Religion

You said it's a big NO so we pass it (even if it's somehow a stronger way than politic to make it work, and can work without force)

### Using mass manipulation

Force some kind of "more petlike" beastfolk to be look as beautyfull is a way to bypass the incounscious choice of "strong" attributes. That why we not always targeting giant muscular warriors men, fat peoples and large hips women (even if we still have some reflex that remains). This method is somehow like the "Let time make it" without forcing. Now you have to wait around 100 000 years (less if you don't have beauties movements that go against what you want).

### Science B*tch!

Using science (considering that you can focus everyone one that) can work. In the real world, a chinese scientist used [CRISPR-cas-9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cas9) (sort of copy past in real life with adn) to make some babies immune to some version of HIV. But it's actually not a 100% chance of making the job. If in your world you can have multiple scientists make researches about that, they may create a drug or a virus that can change the beastfolk genitals adn so they give birth to petfolk. It's the "easiest" way, can be done without force (unless release that in air is force for you) and it's selective since you select what caracteristics you can have.